# C#: Post JSON data to Web API on a WordPress / Woocommerce Website

Tags: c#, php, curl

We have had a plugin developed that will allow us to upload product data for a Woocommerce-based ecommerce website from our desktop-based accounts package. The developer has provided code of how to upload the data using CURL / PHP, testing this and it does work as expected. However, am experiencing issues getting it to work from our account package which is written in C#

The data to be uploaded is posted as JSON data. See sample below.

```
{   
  "v": "imaverifiedupload",
  "products": [ {
    "type": "simple",   
    "name": "Fallout: New Vegas Endpoint check",
    "description": "Fallout: New Vegas (PS3)",
    "sku": "093", 
    "product_category": "310",  
    "sub_category": "370", 
    "price": "2.50",     
    "manage_stock": 1,     
    "quantity": 0,      
    "image_name": "fallout_3_ps3.jpg"   
  } ] 
}
```

This is the PHP code the developer gave us:

```
<?php   
  $endpoint_url = 'https://xxx.xxx/oogabooga/wp-json/custom/v1/import';  
  
  $param='{ "v": "imaverifiedupload",   
            "products": [ {
            "type": "simple",     
             "name": "Fallout: New Vegas Endpoint check",
             "description": "Fallout: New Vegas (PS3)",
             "sku": "093",     
             "product_category": "310",     
             "sub_category": "370",
             "price": "2.50",     
             "manage_stock": 1,     
             "quantity": 0,      
             "image_name": "fallout_3_ps3.jpg"   
           }] }'; 

  // Set your POST data 
  $post_data = array('json_data' => $param); 

  // Initialize cURL session 
  $ch = curl_init($endpoint_url); // Set cURL options 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data)); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

  // Execute cURL session and get the response 
  $response = curl_exec($ch); // Check for cURL errors 
  if (curl_errno($ch)) { 
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); } 

  // Close cURL session 
  curl_close($ch); 

  // Handle the response   
  echo $response; 
?>
```

This my attempt to re-write the code in C#:

```
string endpointUrl = "https://xxx.xxx/oogabooga/wp-json/custom/v1/import";

// Define the parameters                     
NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection  {
  { "json_data", jsonData }, 
};

// Create a WebClient instance                     
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;                                
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;                        
  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; }; 

   // Set the method to POST    
  client.UploadValues(endpointUrl, "POST", postData);                          

  try 
  {
    // Perform the POST request and get the response  
    byte[] responseBytes = client.UploadValues(endpointUrl, "POST", postData);                         

    string response = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);                                   
    
    // Handle the response 
    Console.WriteLine(response);                         
  } 
  catch (WebException ex)
  {
    // Handle any errors                             
    Console.WriteLine("WebException: " + ex.Message);                         
  }
}
```

This is the exception I get:

[Exception Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ft4T.jpg)

Whenever I run this I get a HTTP Code 500 error.

Does anyone have any idea where I am going wrong here?

Comment: Go and check what the error log has to say about the _cause_ of the 500 first of all.

Comment: Your `jsonData` in the C# version, is that actually a string value? If not, this might get "serialized" differently, than what PHP actually sends. _"The data to be uploaded is posted as JSON data."_ - the PHP version does not actually make a JSON request, it sends _one_ parameter named `json_data` in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

Comment: So the plugin accepts JSON data wrapped in form-urlencoded data? Yuk. Sorry but your plugin developer seems to have been a bit clueless about data formats.

Comment: @CBroe Yes jsonData in the C# code is a string.  I appreciate the PHP isn't making a JSON request. Also asked the server owners for the logs ...

Comment: So the `jsonData` variable in C# contains exactly the same string as `$param` does in the PHP? Is that correct?

Comment: P.S. Any specific reason you're using WebClient in this day and age? Microsoft specifically recommends that you use HttpClient instead - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-8.0#remarks

Comment: Your code does client.UploadValues twice. Is that intentional?

Comment: @ADyson, jsonData will be a string in the same format at the $param var in the PHP code.

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper, no and good spot, Thanks!

Comment: @ADyson Have been dredging the ol' google for an answer and trying suggestions that have worked for others, this code is made of what I've got from the search. Right now I just need to get this to work, I can always tweak, better the solution down the line

Comment: Well obviously getting the cause of the 500 error might help to point you in the right direction, in case what you're sending is making the server crash (although you'd hope it would have better validation than that!), but I'd always start by using the most up to date Microsoft libraries, in case it uses better data-formatting logic! I can't believe there are no examples out there for sending POST data via HttpClient!!

Comment: If you have Postman installed, you could see the code for PHP cURL requests and respective C# code(Postman shows C# code using RestClient, but it should point you in the right direction).

Comment: Problem solved. Ended up been just incorrectly formatted JSON. Am now validating the JSON before submission. Also changed from WebClient to HTTPClient too! Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: That's great. If you think the solution would be of benefit to others then please post an Answer below showing what you had to do to resolve it. See also [answer]. If it was just something trivial though, maybe just delete the question. Don't leave it open and hanging around though - thanks.